# Cached $resource will not be updated correctly

Tags: angularjs

Iam using a cached $resource to interact with a REST API:

```
.factory('OpeningHours', function($resource, $cookies){
    return $resource(apiBase + '/api/test', {}, {
      'get' : { method:'GET', cache: true }
    });
  });
```

How i get the data with help of the factory:

```
OpeningHours.get({}, function(response){
      $scope.openingHours = response;
    });
```

And i update the $resource like so:

```
$scope.save = function(){
  $scope.openingHours.$save();
}
```

The new data will be post to the server correctly, but the $resource object will not be updated. If i change the view and go back i got the old data. Only after i reload the whole application, the $resource object contain the new data (because the API will be called). If i turn of the caching, all works as expected.

How can i force AngularJS to update the data in the $resource object and additional use caching?

Comment: How do you add the new data to the scope before saving?

Comment: $scope.openingHours holds form data, so data will be added by ng-model

Comment: the data will initial loaded by route resolve

Comment: I get what you mean. I suppose you need a way of updating the content of the cache whenever there is a change. But do you really need a cache if the resource changes often?

Comment: @tschiela, have you found an answer to this?

Comment: @gustavohenke i use the $cacheFactory to implemt my own caching functionality. Thats a little work if you do this for every resource but it's worth it.

Comment: Yeah, after some hours spent on this I ended up caching GETs and destroying them when there are POST/PUT/DELETE requests. Thanks anyway